# What are ways to update a windows form application?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I need suggestions on how to update my application. The form application is going to be put on a drive for many users to be using non stop all day. What are ways to update the program or allow updates to the program while it being use? If I update the program and recreate a new build for it, trying to copy paste over the old application will not let me if someone else has it open. Open to any suggestions.

Comment: Deployment is a tricky thing.  There are a bunch of different approaches and products that address this.  At the firm I work for, I just deploy on restart via MSI and Active Directory Group Policy.  Unfortunately, that's the best we can do for the reasons you've cited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1:** Deploy the app with ClickOnce and set it to check for updates every time it runs.

**ClickOnce:**

In your project settings, click on the Publish tab.

From here you can configure where the app publishes to and if it should be installed or available online only.

Once you have it all configured you will use the Publish Now button to compile and upload your update to the publish location. Each time your users open the app it will check for updates at your set location. To have your app check for updates programmatically use code like the one found at this MSDN link - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404263.aspx

You should note that users will no longer run an exe directly and you won't copy your exe to the publish folder. Your users will have to click on a file that has the extension of .application. The users could create a shortcut to this .application file to place on their desktop or wherever they want.

Also note that if using ClickOnce and you publish a bad version (with a bug for instance) then your users have the ability to revert back to the previous version so that they can continue using the app while you fix the bug. Your users also have the option to skip an update so you'll want to inform them to never skip the updates.

**Option 2:** Create an app that publishes your main app

I'll admit that this answer is not a great way

You could create another exe for the purpose of publishing the main exe. The publishing exe will simply try to copy the new exe over the old one and keep trying until it is successful. It will be successful when all instances of the program are terminated.

**Option 3:** Use a database
Have your app check a database value that indicates an update is available. Prompt users using the app to shutdown and don't allow other instances to startup while the database value is set to update available.

Comment: Why is this down voted. This is a valid way to accomplish what he wants.

Comment: Does that mean the app will have to be installed on everyone's user's computer/login crediticals ect?

Comment: Not necessarily. You can change the setting to only allow it to run from the published location. You also have the option to install it. Both ways work just as well.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but as it stands, you aren't offering much information here — this is more of a comment.  That will attract down votes.

Comment: It's the solution. Sure i could edit it to be a tutorial on how to use ClickOnce, but it's so easy that one could just Google it. I provided the solution, but I did not show how to implement it.

Comment: @MichaelZ. I understand the published location but I'm only putting out the .exe file to the folder for everyone to use. How would I change the original .exe file if it is opened? - if user did not install the app and only using the .exe built file.

Comment: You won't directly publish the exe anymore and the users won't run an exe. Instead they will launch a file that has the extension of .application.

Comment: You can publish while users are using the app, but they won't get the update until they restart. You could go even further and in your code you could check if there are updates and if so then prompt your user to restart the app which will automatically update the app for them.

Comment: @MichaelZ. : It's not _the_ solution, but _a_ solution. There are hundreds, maybe even thousands of solutions. :)

Comment: I down voted exactly for the reason LarsTech said.  At the time I downvoted, your answer was pretty bare.  I will retract it now.

Comment: @VisualVincent yes you are correct. I meant to write it as "a solution" not "the solution" sorry

Comment: @roryap thank you, I am sorry it was so bare. I will be better about that going forward.

Comment: @MichaelZ. I setup according to your instructions. I now have myApp.application. When I click on it, it prompts to install on computer. I don't want to install, I just want to use the app?

Comment: It's not installing like normal programs do. It has to do it this way so you can publish while other users are using the app. You can check out my other two options. Option 2 and 3 would allow you to continue using the exe directly. Option 3 will only work if you have a centralized database.

Comment: You should be aware though, that if using ClickOnce option and you publish a bug then users have the ability to revert the update to the previous version. Also, users can skip updates so you would have to inform your users to never skip an update.

Comment: is there a way to disable skipping updates and only revert versions on admin's end?

Comment: I've never had to disable skipping update or limiting the users allowed to revert to a previous version. I'll mess around with a test app to see if I can give you a solution to those.

Comment: by the way, after successfully publishing to the destination path folder, after trying again, I'm getting publish errors: "could not copy "obj\Debug\myApp.exe" to "bin\Debug\myApp.exe. ........the process is being used by another process.

Comment: Each update should go into the publish folder as its own sub folder named after the version. Did you just use your Bin folders as a publish location for testing?

Comment: I'm looking at one of my publish folders and it doesn't even copy the exe with the .exe extension. Each file uses a .deploy extension. There might be something wrong with the way you have the ClickOnce setup.

Comment: for updates just curious, if you make any changes to application and publish. the app.application gets replaced with new app.application, there's really no prompt for users to update or not is there when they are already running the application?

Comment: If you want your users to be alerted to updates while they are using the app then you can use a timer that checks for updates and if found prompt the user to update and restart the app. Check this link for the code to check for updates programmatically. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404263.aspx

Comment: thanks you. works as it should. I wonder why when publish, it gives you app.application and the setup.exe, anyway to stop publishing the setup.exe ?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the setup.exe just launches the .application file. I have never tried to exclude it so I am not certain if this is possible. I'll look into it and If I find anything I'll update my post. It's possible that the setup.exe plays a role in installing the prerequisites too.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [nUpdate](https://github.com/ProgTrade/nUpdate), a free and open-source .NET-library for updating applications that also cares about the safety of your update packages which is an important fact. Many update routines do not validate the packages they downloaded, which can result in serious damage, if updates are replaced by malware (as it happened to the puush-service some time ago).

nUpdate is especially designed for Windows Forms-applications.
It is still being improved at the moment and the support for WPF-applications will be added soon, but the current version is very stable, yet.

Comment: I've never heard of this. I will check this out myself. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Seems to be great update library. Unfortunately, the project seems to be quite dead :(.

Comment: @thefiloe Currently, it's paused, yes. Nevertheless, version 4.0.0 will be coming. ;)